# Is there a way for one method to get the next value from a generator in another method?

Tags: python, pandas, generator

I have a generator in my get_new_point method that retrieves a tuple of data from a dataframe within a dict. Ideally when I run the update_trailing_points method, it would retrieve the next tuple from the generator. However, when I actually run the update_trailing_points method, it returns the same tuple every time (the first line from the dataframe). What am I doing wrong here?

Let me explain my data structures because I know they may be a little confusing:

all_data is a dict of dataframes. The keys are 'symbols'

symbol_list is a list of the keys (symbols)

```
    def get_new_point(self,symbol):
        for i in self.all_data[symbol].index:
            yield tuple([self.all_data[symbol]['timestamp'][i],\ 
                         self.all_data[symbol]['point'][i])

    def update_trailing_points(self):
        for s in self.symbol_list:
            try:
                new_point = self.get_new_point(s).__next__()
            except StopIteration:
                self.continue_test = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.get_new_point(s)` returns a generator object.

```
new_point = self.get_new_point(s).__next__()
```

You're re-initializing the generator every time this piece of code runs. 
You should be making the `self.get_new_point(s)` call only once, but `__next__()` on that object multiple times.

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

That's not how generators are used. Check this:

```
def test(n):
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

# bad: creates a new generator every time.
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    print(test(n).__next__())

# good: creates a single generator then iterates over it
n = 10
t = test(n)
for i in range(n):
    print(next(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, your `get_new_point` can be "improved":

```
def make_point_generator(self, symbol):
    df = self.all_data[symbol][['timestamp', 'point']]
    yield from df.itertuples(index=False)
```

It would be advisable to use `pandas` functionality directly wherever possible!

I assume that you want a generator over points. Then:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__gens = None

def update_trailing_points(self):
    if self.__gens is None:
        self.__gens = {s: self.make_point_generator(s) for s in self.symbol_list}

    for s in self.symbol_list:
        try:
            new_point = next(self.__gens[s])
        except StopIteration:
            self.continue_test = False
```